# Method won't Update DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const locale = {
    fr: {
        login_page_title_welcome: "a",

        BKUE_status: "b",
        UNCN_status: "c",
        NNTA_status: "d",
    }
};

var l = locale["fr"];

$.fn.locale=function(i) {

    this.html(l.i);
    this.attr('locale', ""+i+"");
};
```

I have the `const` and I want to update an elements html and add an attribute using a custom method.

```
login_div_UNCN.locale('UNCN_status');
```

The `attribute` is added by the method. But the `html` is not updated.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You left out how `login_div_UNCN` is created.

Comment: Also `locale.fr` does not have a child property of `i` for `html(l.i);` to work.  You need to use `l[i]` if `i` is the variable for the property

Comment: What is the context of `this`?

Comment: @Taplar Its a const linked to an ID of a DIV.

Comment: @Taplar If I were to use `l.login_div_UNCN` it works. Why do I need `l[login_div_UNCN]`. Don't get it?

Comment: Ok, so then you just need to fix your incorrect usage of `l.i`.  Because `l.i` expects `l` to be a variable and `i` to be the **literal** name of the property.  In this case it is not.  It's a variable.  So to make javascript understand it is a variable, you use bracket notation, so it uses the variable as a reference for the actual property name based on its value

Comment: @Taplar Ok, `l[i]` works as intended. Can you please explain why this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)